# PHP time-out on shared hosting

Tags: php

I have a script but my server on shared hosting times out after 5 minutes, is there a way to continue script after time-out? The script updates my MySQL database.
Do run script for some time and stop then continue automatically but not from the start?

Thanks

Comment: If you need more than 5 minutes for your script to complete, I'm hoping we're talking about a cronjob? These shouldn't have time limits by default, as the [PHP manual](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) states: "When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.". If it does, ask your hosting provider if this limit can be adjusted.

Comment: Yes I mean use it as cron job and I have just five minutes

Comment: OK, well then contact your hosting provider or use software limits like parsing 1000 database rows per run or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automatically continue script after terminated execution. On shared hosting environments it is common to kill scripts after some time, you should check how long it is allowed to run on your hosting's company wiki / faq. If you want to simulate continuing script execution, you must code it yourself, detecting what has been done and processing only the rest of data.